# Undefined is not a function near '..'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been getting this error and even after few searches I have not been able to find the solution to it. I am new to node and javascript so any help will be cherished.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ4sP.jpg)

In written form the code is provided below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


export const ItemForm = ({ addItemProp }) => {
  const [Name, setName] = useState("");
  const [Price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [description, setdescription] = useState("");
  const [Product, setProduct] = useState("");
  const [imagepath, setimagepath] = useState("");
  const [Category, setCategory] = useState("");




const addItem = _=> { 
    addItemProp({
      id: (new Date).getTime(),
      Name,
      Price,
      description, 
      Product,
      Category,
      imagepath,
    });
    setName('')
    setPrice('');
    setdescription('');
    setProduct('');
    setCategory('');
    setimagepath('');
  }
```

and the error I am getting is :
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...addItemProp...')
addItem
src/Components/AddProduct/addProduct.jsx:14

```
  13 |        const addItem = _=> { 
  14 |        addItemProp({
  15 |        id: (new Date).getTime(),
  16 |        Name,
  17 |        Price,
```

Comment: Does adding a semicolon after `setName('')` helps?

Comment: I think it's saying that `addItemProp` might be undefined.

Comment: addItemProp seems to be undefined at the time of component load, I would suggest using a '?' and see if it resolves, like so  `const addItem = _=> { 
    addItemProp?({
      id: (new Date).getTime(),
      Name,
      Price,
      description, 
      Product,
      Category,
      imagepath,
    });
    setName('')
    setPrice('');
    setdescription('');
    setProduct('');
    setCategory('');
    setimagepath('');
  } `

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman adding semicolon does not help, still it shows undefined

Comment: @otejiri No, it didn't help me either

Comment: @PrashantShrestha I will need to see the component that the `addItemProp` is passed from. It should contain `<ItemForm addItemProp={() => function.... />`

Comment: @otejiri It is present in the question above. Or is it different ?

Comment: @PrashantShrestha `addItemProp` is being sent by another component to the `ItemForm` component. I was asking to see the parent component